# How do I group a new variable based on a variables first letter?

Tags: r

I have a variable that is alphanumeric, ex: A890. I have over 1 million records and all 26 letters of the alphabet are used to start the variable, and I would like to know how to many of these records (the count) start with a given letter. Ideally creating a table would be great. Ex:

```
A - 2,900
B - 784,090
Etc.
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you can use?

```
x <- c("A1234", "A234", "B7654", "A76768", "C980", "A767", "Z90898")

library(stringr)
table(str_extract(x, "^[A-Z]"))

A B C Z 
4 1 1 1
```

Here you extract the upper-case letter occurring in first position in the string and tabulate the result.

Comment: if the character is always at first place a similar approach could be used: `table(str_sub(data, start=1L, end=1L))`

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer:

```
> df <- data.frame(name = c('A123','A2321','B32','B3232','C098','A989','C321','D233','D123','B2132'),
+                  value = round(rnorm(10,100,2),2))
> df %>% group_by(substr(name,1,1)) %>% summarise(occurances = n())
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  `substr(name, 1, 1)` occurances
  <chr>                     <int>
1 A                             3
2 B                             3
3 C                             2
4 D                             2
>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` solution

```r
library(dplyr)

df2 <- data.frame(alphanumeric = c(rep("A890", 5), rep("B2011", 8)))

df2 %>% 
   mutate(starter = substr(x = alphanumeric, 1, 1)) %>% 
   group_by(starter) %>% 
   tally

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   starter     n
#>   <chr>   <int>
#> 1 A           5
#> 2 B           8
```